# My Python App can't open after successfully registered in eureka server

Tags: python, spring-boot, flask, microservices, netflix-eureka

I have python app using Flask for my project and i need to registered the service to Eureka server. The flask is successfully registered and appeared in Eureka server, but i can't access it with eureka server URL. This is my code:

```
eureka_client.init(eureka_server="https://server.url/eureka/", app_name="my-app", instance_port=int(port)instance_secure_port_enabled=True)
```

When i try it to GET from postman, the result is 404 not found. Is anyone know what should i complete?

Thank you for your help

Comment: what do you mean by I can't access it. If you see it in eureka server that it means it registered its address with service data. you can check via GET /eureka/v2/apps/appID to see how it is registered. You can also check if the registered url is accessible.

Comment: Eureka sever only host the information of all the components. It's not a gateway, so the request won't get through the eureka server.